# Cannot get session in webmethod in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I just find that the problem is not related to the webmethod.

It is caused by another problem.

I set the `Session["PhotoId"]` in a normal aspx.
But I can't retrieve value in the `webMethod` of the aspx page.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    public static string Submit(string data1, ...)
    {
        string test = HttpContext.Current.Session["PhotoId"]; // test is null
    }
```

What should I do?

Comment: check if the sessionid is same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I see, everything should be fine here.

As far as HttpContext.Current.Session is not null, session state is supported here.
Please ensure, that you set Session["PhotoId"].

You can test whether it is the same session by examining

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID
```

in both normal ASPX and WebMethod.

Comment: The session Id is different. This helps me solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: How or why SessionId could be different?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ToString()` method to use session as a string.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public static string Submit(string data1, ...)
{
    string test = HttpContext.Current.Session["PhotoId"].ToString(); 
}
```