# session is not working in webservice despite enabling it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session

I am trying to use session varaibles to store some values in one webservice like this

```
         Session["Url"] = linkDetails.Url;
        Session["Title"] = linkDetails.Title;
        Session["Description"] = linkDetails.Description;
        Session["Favicon"] = linkDetails.Favicon.Url;
        Session["Image"] = linkDetails.Image.Url;
```

I have set the `[WebMethod(enablesessionstate=true)]`. and then I try to retrieve these value in another webservice like this

```
     string Url = Session["Url"].ToString();
     string Title = Session["Title"].ToString();
     string Description = Session["Description"].ToString();
     string Favicon = Session["Favicon"].ToString();
     string Image = Session["Image"].ToString();
```

but when I check the Session `keys` it is null. I have the `enablesessionstate=true`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot get session in webmethod in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340445/cannot-get-session-in-webmethod-in-asp-net)

Comment: Hey!!! @Darren Thanks... You have such a bird eye view.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you can access session variables from webservice ,but cannot assign session variables by using [WebMethod(enablesessionstate=true)].